# How to get a particular object from JSON array [Android]

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a response json like this,

```
[{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
},
{
  "userId": 2,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
},
{
  "userId": 3,
  "id": 3,
  "title": "omnis laborum odio"
}]
```

I want to show detail from userId = 3, I wasn't provided an endpoint to get detail. So I want to get detail from this endpoint.

in App:

- I've shown the data for dashboard (using recyclerview/list)
- After that, I want to go to detail from one data that I selected.
- Case: I'm using 1 endpoint (like above)

Comment: Go over the JSON Array and check for the property userId and see if it equals 3.

Comment: how should i do, in java?

Comment: No it's json already. The case, I just want to get {"userId" : 3, "id" : 3, "title" : "omnis laborum odio"}

Answer (score 0):

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSON.parse(str);
        Map map = jsonArray.stream().map( obj -> {JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) obj;return jsonobject;}).collect(Collectors.toMap(obj->obj.getIntValue("userId"),obj->obj.toJSONString()));
        System.out.println(map.get(3));
```

Answer (score -2):

the start point of `json` must always be a `jsonObject` not `jsonArray`. head to your backend developer and ask him or her to put your `jsonArray` inside a jsonObject.

```
{
    "docs":[{
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
      },
      {
        "userId": 3,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "omnis laborum odio"
      }]
}
```